# Cron job output in wrong Linux folder

Tags: python, linux, path, cron

This is my first post here.  I am a very big fan of Stack Overflow.  This is the first time I could not find an answer to one of my questions.

Here is the scenario:

In my Linux system, I am not an admin or root.  When I run a Python script, the output appears in the original folder, however when I run the same Python script as a Cron job, it appears in my accounts home folder.    Is there anything I can do to direct the output to a desired folder?   I do have the proper shebang path.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If the output comes from inside the python script, you may replace the entry in your cron from:

```
  python yourscript.py
```

with

```
 (cd thepath && python yourscript.py)
```

If it's the stderr stdout, you should instead use:

```
 (cd thepath && python yourscript.py >> output.log 2>&1)
```

I personally prefer to use either a wrapping bash script or a genuine local python install in a local PYTHONPATH refered to by your .bashrc rather than from the "development" path. It has the significant advantage of not requiring to mod the crontab entry when you need/want to modify anything from the script.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the output of your cronjob like this:

```
$ crontab -e
59 23 * * * python /home/nodeman/documents/myscripts/my-script.py > /home/nodeman/logs/my-script.log 2>&1
```

Comment: or you can use `59 23 * * * ( cd /some/where; python my.py; )`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses after further searching, I found this that worked:

*/1 * * * * /home/ranveer/vimbackup.sh >> /home/ranveer/vimbackup.log 2>&1